# How can I pass multiple arguements from Django Template to View via URL?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying a simple thing User clicks a question displayed. The link when clicked would take in the question id and pass it as an argument to display the relevant Choices. The user is asked to chose a Choice and then the next page would display how many people has voted for that Choice(including the user's current decision).
The Error I am getting is when I start the app using 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ it displays the question. Then when I click the question the url becomes 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/ which is correct as 3 is the question id. So it is expected to show the Choices for the Question ID. But it is not showing. 
The Error is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/3/

Reverse for 'results' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'q_id': 3, 'c_test': 'May Be'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<q_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<c_test>\\w+)/results/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/
Django Version:     1.10.3
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'results' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'q_id': 3, 'c_test': 'May Be'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<q_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<c_test>\\w+)/results/$']

Exception Location:     /home/usr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3.5
Python Version:     3.5.2
```

My code is:

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = "polls/index.html"
  context_object_name = "latest_question_list"
  model = Question

def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(ListView):
   model = Choice
   context_object_name = "latest_choice_list"
   template_name = "polls/detail.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    print(self.args[0])
    '''Return list of choices'''
    return Choice.objects.filter(question_id=self.args[0])
    # return Choice.objects.all()

def pollvote(request, q_id, c_test):

 if c_test:
    p = Choice.objects.filter(question_id=q_id).get(choice_test=c_test)
    count = p.votes
    count += 1
    p.votes = count
    p.save()

return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/%s/%s/results/' % c_test, q_id)
```

detail.html (error says problem at the href line)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
{% if latest_choice_list %}
    <p>Cast your Choice</p>
<ul>


    {% for choice in latest_choice_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'polls:results' q_id=choice.question_id c_test=choice.choice_test%}">{{ choice.choice_test }}</a></li>


    {% endfor %}
</ul>


{% else %}
<p>No choice are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

results.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
{% if latest_choice_list %}
    <p>Choices Made So Far</p>
<ul>
    {% for choice in latest_choice_list %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_test  }} - {{ choice.votes }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
<p>No choice are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^([0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),    
url(r'^(?P<q_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<c_test>\w+)/results/$', views.pollvote, name='results'),]
```

Why is the detail.html is throwing error? Why is it not taking the two keyword named arguement and passing it to the result?

Comment: maybe that's issue of Ctrl+V, but the indentation in views.py obviously incorrect

Comment: No that is correct in the real code. It is a copy-paste issue here while posting the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:results' choice.question_id choice.choice_test%}">{{ choice.choice_test }}</a>
```

Django will automatically assign the args in given order.

**P.S.**

- I am assuming that Choice model has question_id and choice_test field.
- If you have question_id as an integer field as a reference to any Question object then instead of doing this, you can use Foreign key field of django.medels . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Hi, I did what you said.But still the same. The only thing that changed is now it says 
Reverse for 'results' with arguments '(3, 'May Be')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<q_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<c_test>\\w+)/results/$']
instead of keyword args it now takes in args only. And still sys error with detail.html
And my choice table has got both the fields.
CREATE TABLE "polls_choice" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "choice_test" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "votes" integer NOT NULL, "question_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "polls_question" ("id"));

Comment: I haven't looked your comment in depth but I think \w only matches the characters and underscore. It doesn't match space. So change regex in urls.py